# How to stop Vim from scrolling when save file with splitting vertically

Tags: vim

```
+-----------------+-----------------+            
|                 |                 |            
|                 |                 |            
|                 |                 |            
|       A         |       B         |            
|                 |                 |            
|                 |                 |            
|                 |                 |            
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

as you see, I split the vim vertically, and pane A and pane B are open **the same file**. while I edit file in pane A, and use `:w` to save, file in pane B scroll to the end.

How to stop pane B scrolling in this case?

Comment: Plain Vim should not be doing it. Does it still do it when you do `vim -u NONE`? If so, something is wrong with your system. If not, then one of your settings or plugins is doing it; start switching them off to see which one is messing you up.

Comment: Looks like a `BufWritePost` autocommand.

Comment: yes, when I use `vim -u NONE`, everything is ok @Amadan

Comment: could you please give more info? @romainl

Comment: Without access to your config it's hard to do better than a shot in the dark. Like… you have a formatting plugin/command that's supposed to work on save; a badly configured linter; or anything, really. Grepping your `~/.vim` for `BufWritePost` could probably help.

Comment: thx for your advice, I finally got it might be `vim-go` plugin, when I use `:w` to save go file, it use `go fmt` to format my file. @romainl